# How can I remove the floor function from ⌊ab/10⌋?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

After several weeks of trying on my own, I was hoping for a hand. I am familiar with transitioning ⌊ab/10⌋ to a mod function as well as a trig function. Ideally, I would like a solution that involved nothing more than */+-.

Thank you,

### -Erick

a and b are whole numbers with any value from 0 to 9.

---

Based on the answers here, this is impossible with only the arithmetic symbols. This however leads me to ask if this would be possible with an integral or summation?

Comment: what are a and b? integers, ? natural numbers?

Comment: You can't. There's no way to express the floor function with just the four basic operations.

Comment: @Deusovi: See my answer for one way; it's possible if you only want the floor function on a finite domain. Note that my answer could have been applied directly to the $1$-input floor function, but the general technique applies even for multiple-input functions on reals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer you got that says it's impossible is wrong if you only have finitely many inputs. Let $D = \{0..9\}$ and the desired function be $f : D^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. Consider the function $g$ defined for any $x,y \in D$ by:
$\def\less{\smallsetminus}$

> $g(x,y) = \sum_{a,b \in D} f(x,y) \dfrac{ \prod_{c \in D \less \{a\}} (x-c) }{ \prod_{c \in D \less \{a\}} (a-c) } \dfrac{ \prod_{d \in D \less \{b\}} (x-d) }{ \prod_{d \in D \less \{b\}} (b-d) }$.

This is valid since the denominators are non-zero.

Also notice that $g(x,y) = f(x,y)$ for any $x,y \in D$, because in the outer summation every term vanishes except the one where $⟨a,b⟩ = ⟨x,y⟩$, and in that one remaining term the products cancel. Symbolically, $\dfrac{ \prod_{c \in D \less \{a\}} (x-c) }{ \prod_{c \in D \less \{a\}} (a-c) } = \mathbf{1}_{x=a}$ for any $x \in D$, and likewise for the other factor.

Therefore there is a polynomial of degree at most $2|D|^2$ that exactly matches $f$ on $D^2$.

Hence we get a formula in $x,y$ using only arithmetic operations for any expression in terms of $x,y$ where $x,y \in D$, including "$\lfloor \frac{xy}{10} \rfloor$". The above technique generalizes to any function with arbitrary number of inputs from a field.

Comment: But it is correct that if you want a formula that works for **real** $x,y \in [0,10)$, then it is impossible since the desired function is discontinuous on $[0,10)$.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: I didn't say even "wrong" per se. I said "wrong **if** ...". However, the asker **did** specify discrete inputs: "a and b are whole numbers with any value from 0 to 9." Furthermore, your answer states a falsehood claiming that it is impossible for **integers** $x,y$ from $0$ to $9$. That in particular is why I said it the way I did in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but for future readers I had to point out that your comment was incorrect since the asker did want a function on discrete points. A more interesting question would be to ask what is the least-degree polynomial that matches the required function.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: If you don't state precisely what you mean, your statement makes no sense. Any power series that is bounded on a sequence tending to the boundary of convergence will converge at the boundary point. So power series won't work. Fourier series also don't work because of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: If you don't specify what series you're referring to, your comment is **meaningless** because it states **nothing at all**. Don't tell me I'm limiting my point of view when you don't know what you're saying. There is **trivially** the infinite sum $\def\nn{\mathbb{N}}\def\ii{\mathbf{1}}$$\lfloor x \rfloor = \sum_{k \in \nn} ( \ii(x \ge k+1) - \ii(-x \ge k) )$, where $\ii$ is the indicator function.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: That very infinite series that you just mentioned is Fourier series, which I **already** mentioned above. The link you gave states **clearly** that it does **not** converge to the same value at the discontinuities. Therefore it does **not** match. You don't even pay any attention to what I say. So stubborn!

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Furthermore, that wikipedia article is **wrong** about the reason for the lack of uniform convergence of the Fourier series. It is **not** because it is non-periodic, but due to the jump discontinuities. See the wikipedia article that **I gave earlier**. In particular, the floor and ceil functions are non-periodic and hence **do not even have** a Fourier series, contrary to your claim, and differ at discontinuities even if you restrict to a bounded interval! The article hence also incorrectly implies that the fractional part function has a uniformly convergent Fourier series!

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Look your original comment said "Infinite degree would actually match the floor function.". That is **utterly meaningless**, as I've already explained. **Enough. I'm wasting my time to help you.**

Answer (score 3):

If by removing the floor function you mean that when $\lfloor {ab/10}\rfloor =ab/10$, then the only way you can remove the floor function is making sure that $ab/10$ is a whole number. From the comments you said that $a,b$ are whole numbers between 0 and 9, so the only way $10=2\times 5$ divides $ab$ is that 2 divides $a$ and 5 divides $b$, or the same with the roles of $a$ and $b$ interchanged. This implies that $a\in\{0,2,4,6,8\}$ and that $b\in\{0,5\}$ (or the other way around)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. The function you gave us is a discontinuous multivariate function. In order to express it, one must use a discontinuous function. Therefore, for all x and y that are integers from 0 to 9, there is no arithmetic function that equals the function you gave.

Comment: Actually, this function IS continuous! The domain of this function is the $100$ point space $\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid a,b\in\{0,1,...,9\}\}$, whose subspace topology is the discrete topology. Every function is continuous with respect to the discrete topology!

Comment: I never said I could? I was just pointing out that the function is a continuous function so your argument doesn't work.

Comment: Also, look at the accepted answer, as it proves the existence of a polynomial that does the job.

Comment: If we were talking about on the domain of real numbers, I would agree with you. We aren't talking about that though. On a finite discrete space, you can create a polynomial that equals the floor function.

Comment: Yeah, kind of. It isn't a Taylor series(which isn't a polynomial, but a power series), just a polynomial that matches the output of the floor function at the $100$ points in the domain.

Comment: One variant is called a Newton polynomial. And you should edit your post to say that your answer is for the case when you want the floor function for all reals in some interval that contains a jump discontinuity. So that at least it says something true.